# How can I bind ctrl+1 to select first tab?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

How can I bind ctrl+1 to select the first tab in Visual Studio 2010?

If you are unsure of what I mean, try having multiple tabs open in Google Chrome and try ctrl+1,2,3 to switch between them.

I also have ReSharper - if that helps.

Comment: May I ask, why do you think you need this? Do you need to continuously navigate back to a specific file?

Comment: @gorohoroh: Really, I want to be able to bind ctrl+n to the nth tab... but if I could solve ctrl+1 to the first tab, I would be able to fix the others.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't really see a point in opening a n-numbered tab if it's irrelevant of its content. If you're looking to bookmark specific content, you can use ReSharper bookmarks: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Bookmarks.html

Comment: If I were to change tab, I would have to use the mouse (I don't like moving my hands from the keyboard) or I could use ctrl+shift+tab, but in that case I can't specify directly which tab to go for. To sum it up - using ctrl+1,2,3 provides an easy and fast way to navigate between tabs.

Comment: I was just assuming that since you're using ReSharper, with all the navigation features that it has, you're pretty much independent of tab switching actions as you have bookmarks, Go to symbol/file/type, Go to recent edits/recent files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explore on Visual Studio Extension "[**Productivity Power Tool**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)", it already has this kind of tab navigation.

- Activate a specific regular tab by Ctrl+Alt+Num Pad 1 through 0
- Activate a specific pinned tab by Ctrl+Num Pad 1 through 0

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/

Comment: Yes, binding command 'Window.GoToUnpinnedTab1' to ctrl + 1 solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With ReSharper. Open your first tab, click anywhere in the text and press Ctrl+Shift+1 (or 2, 3, etc.) to place ReSharper's bookmark. Then you can open this tab and go to this bookmark by pressing Ctrl+1 (2, 3, etc) even if you have other tab open. Exactly as you want.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a late response but I did this in a way without using an extension.

I created a menu item (if you're using WFA) and created tool strip menu items named like: tab0ToolStripMenuItem ect.

I set the menu item visible property to `False` and each menu item to ShortcutKeys like Ctrl+1

Then tided the click events to:

```
private void tab0ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void tab1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
}

private void tab2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
}

private void tab3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 3;
}
```

Probably a poor and newbie way of doing this but it works,  I hope this helps you or anyone else looking to this.

Comment: I am pretty sure he is referring to Visual Studio itself, not his own program.

Comment: Yep after re-reading OP's question you're correct.  My bad, I should have understood that originally.  Got to excited thinking I had an answer.